# How to make link between LocalApp project to RemoteApp project in standalone maven?

Tags: class, maven-3

I created one LocalApp project and one RemoteApp project. I used some classes of RemoteApp project in my LocalApp project.

I added dependencies like group id, artifact, version and scope of RemoteApp into pom.xml of LocalApp but while executing LocalApp from command prompt, I got `NoClassDefFoundException` which means those inherited classes of RemoteApp are not visible in LocalApp.

How can I help LocalApp find the classes from RemoteApp?

Comment: What are LocalApp and RemoteApp ? And where is the "not found" classes ?

Comment: LocalApp and RemoteApp are two sample apps, lets say hello world example. while executing LocalApp from command prompt like "java -cp localapp-snapshot.jar com.local.Sample". In Sample.java file I used RemoteApp class.

Comment: Running using java -cp ... ? Then did you put a reference to the jar of the remote app ? eg: `java -cp 'remloteapp-snapshot.jar:localapp-snapshot.jar' com.local.Sample`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried above one but it is not resolved. I executed like below.   C:LocalApp/target>java -cp 'remloteapp-snapshot.jar:localapp-snapshot.jar' com.local.Sample. It trowing ClassNotFoundException. Would you clarify me where we actually providing the RemoteApp location. Here I specified the dependecies in pom.xml of LocalApp. Let me know where LocalApp picking up the RemoteApp-snapshot.jar.

Comment: You seems to be confused by `maven`, which manage dependencies when compiling, and `java`, which use jars/directories in classpath to find class. If you don't provide at least the same required runtime dependencies than for the compilation, then you will always have a `ClassNotFoundException` for those missing classes. After that being said, there are maven plugins which let you generate a "jar with dependencies" which should build the classpath for you.

Comment: I am working with standalone maven, here I am not using any plugins.

Comment: Look at this then: http://thomassundberg.wordpress.com/2011/03/05/create-an-executable-jar-from-maven/